# How to configure properties file in MyEclipse?

Tags: java, html, jsp, resourcebundle, properties-file

i am trying to retrieve data from a `properties` file into a `dropdown` using `Resourcebundle`
but i am getting the error

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name `Color`, locale en_US
    java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1521)
    java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1260)
```

here color is the name of the properties file

the partial code is :

```
<select name="color2">
<option value="empty">Select Color2</option>
<%
   ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Color");
   Enumeration<String> serverKeys = rb.getKeys();
   while(serverKeys.hasMoreElements())
   {
      String key = (String)serverKeys.nextElement();
      String value = rb.getString(key);
%>
  <option value="<%=rb.getString(key)%>"><%=rb.getString(key)%></option>
<%
   }        
%>
 </select>
```

and the location of properties file is :

`/test/WebRoot/WEB-INF/properties/Color.properties`

`test` is the name of the project

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't really related to MyEclipse but try putting the properties file in the src folder as it will then be on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it at the root level of one of your source paths, or fully qualify the resource name in the call to getBundle, e.g.

```
ResourceBundle myResources =
     ResourceBundle.getBundle("com.example.test.TestProperties");
```

Also check out the docs  [ResourceBundle.getBundle(String, Locale, ClassLoader)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) for more information.